# Raspberry Pi; use geany(.py) to create a new folder and address code to it?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, self-reference, geany, timelapse

Sorry if this is obvious; I'm new to Rpi and Linux in general.
Im trying to create code for a timelapse camera such that when it turns on, it starts taking images and saves them to a folder.

The part I cant find any information on (or if its possible) is how to generate a new(unique) subfolder for each time the code starts running, and then send the new photos to that location?

The actual photo taking code is super simple:

```
for i in range(numphotos):
    camera.capture('/home/pi/Pictures/image{0:06d}.jpg'.format(i))
    sleep(secondsinterval)
```

My current solution is to just dump them all in the same folder with a unique date and time stamp so that if it has to restart, it has a clear beginning and ending:

```
dateraw= datetime.datetime.now()
datetimeformat = dateraw.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M")

for i in range(numphotos):
    camera.capture('/home/pi/Pictures/'+ datetimeformat + '_{0:06d}.jpg'.format(i))
    sleep(secondsinterval)
```

but as ive said, instead of directing it to the pictures folder, is there any way I can write code so it generates a unique folder (maybe based on the date) and sends the images there?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was super simple.

All that was needed was to create a folder at the start time using `os.mkdir()`  , and simply direct the code to it:

```
dateRaw= datetime.datetime.now()
startDateTimeFormat = dateRaw.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S")

os.mkdir('/home/timelapse1/Pictures/' + startDateTimeFormat)

for i in range(numPhotos):
    camera.capture('/home/timelapse1/Pictures/' + startDateTimeFormat +'/{0:06d}.jpg'.format(i))
    sleep(secondsInterval)
```

I wont mark this as the solution just incase there is still something i'm missing, but it is working well.